# Does Apache Groovy have categorical variables?

Tags: r, groovy, categorical-data

Does Apache Groovy support categorical variables? I'm familiar with R and it has leveled factorized vectors. I'd like to know if Apache Groovy has similar functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groovy has "[enums](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)" that let you define a preset amount of custom values.

Example:

```
public enum Day {
    SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY,
    THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY 
}
```